# psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have "dockerized" a Django/PostgreSQL app and try to connect to my database
I have 2 containers: web et db
It works but I can't connect to my postgresql database

I used to ran `docker exec -it coverage_africa_db_1 psql -U postgres` but I got an error

> psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

I try to 'jump' into my container by running the command `docker exec -it aab213f730cd bash` and try to connect using psql command...

> psql -d db_dev

> psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

or

> psql -U postgres

> error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

in fact, none of psql options works...

.env.dev

```
SECRET_KEY=*************************************
DEBUG=1
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
SQL_DATABASE=db_dev
SQL_USER=user
SQL_PASSWORD=user
SQL_HOST=db
SQL_PORT=5432
DATABASE=postgres
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=core.settings.dev
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    web:
        build: ./app
        restart: always
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - ./app/:/usr/src/app
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        env_file:
            - ./.env.dev
        depends_on: 
            - db
    db:
        image: postgres:12.0-alpine
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgres/data/
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=user
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=user
            - POSTGRES_DB=db_dev
volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

Answer (score 1):

With postgres container, this:

```yaml
environment:
- POSTGRES_USER=user
- POSTGRES_PASSWORD=user
- POSTGRES_DB=db_dev
```

defines how the database is initialized. If you didn't change it, you should be able to connect as user 'user' with password 'user'.

If you did change it, then the actual values are those which were present at the first launch. After first launch those credentials are written into the database, which data is on `postgres_data` volume. If you want to delete the data and reinitialize database with new credentials, use `docker-compose down -v`.

Comment: thansk for replying. I did not change it and try ```docker exec -it coverage_africa_db_1 psql -U user``` and got an error ```psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  database "user" does not exist```

Comment: don't understand why in one case it is role does not exist and other case database does not exist

Comment: I already do a docker-compose down (without -v) but did not change anything...

Comment: You named your database 'db_dev' with `POSTGRES_DB=db_dev`. Try `docker exec -it coverage_africa_db_1 psql -d db_dev -U user`.

Comment: You're welcome. Check this page if you want more on those variables https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres .

Comment: A note to say that this worked really well for me . Appreciated.